# R Shiny selectizeInput() - How to show duplicates?

Tags: r, shiny

I want `updateSelectizeInput` to show duplicate values if there are any. I can not seem to find if this is possible. Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)

x <- c("a", "b", "c", "c", "c")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("input", choices = NULL, label = "Input:")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  updateSelectizeInput(session, "input", choices = x, server = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

For the desired result I changed `x` to `x <- c("a", "b", "c", "c ", "c  ")` just to show what my desired result is. Obviously I do not want to place some spaces in the strings.

Comment: So what is the difference between duplicated 'c'?

Comment: `x` is in fact a column of a data frame. So the other columns have different values but column `x`, in this case, can have duplicate values.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done the way you want it, but perhaps you can pre-manipulate the data so that you add numbers in front of each value in the column that correspond to row numbers or similar.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about some workarounds but was wondering if this was possible at all.

Comment: This is not possible for good reason. When you select any one of the "c" options, the return value would be the same. Then how do you know which one was selected? The javascript library [doesn't support it](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/129) and shiny [doesn't support it](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1115). If you really want, you can (as Joe suggested) make the labels all the same but have them return different values.

Comment: With 'selectInput` function we can achieve this. But `selectizeInput` do not allow duplicates.

Comment: Check if it helps you. `x <- c("a", "b", "c", "\nc", "\n\nc")`